# What happens when a dangling pointer is deleted?

Tags: c++

I have heard that it is undefined behaviour.

But what happens actually?

Is it a crash or something else can also happen?

Is it possible that it goes into an infinite loop> If so, then when does this happen?

Comment: This very much depends on particular implementation of C runtime library and configuration (i.e. gcc/msvc would likely behave differently, debug and release heaps of msvc would do different things, etc).

Comment: "What happens actually?" Well, it's undefined, so we don't know. Theoretically it could open your garage door. Perhaps you mean for a specific compiler/OS?

Answer (score 4):

When you access a "dangling pointer" for any reason bad things can happen, nothing can happen, or "stuff" can happen.  It all depends on what is going on.  For example :

```
int* intp = new int;
*intp = 8;
delete intp;
std::cout << "intp: " << *intp << std::endl;
```

This may print 8, it may print some random number, or it might crash.  It all depends on what has happened to the memory since it was deleted.

This is why it is called undefined behavior.  There is zero way of knowing what is going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

It's called 'undefined' due to there being no real way to predict what will happen.

Accessing a dangling pointer can either corrupt the memory if you're writing to something, it can crash the program, you can get a bounds error, or it might point to a new object, depending on what happened to it since you deleted it.

```
void main(){
char *dp = NULL;

   try{
   char c;
   dp = &c;
   }
   catch(...){
   printf("ex thrown");
   }
 /* c falls out of scope */
 /* dp is 'now' a dangling pointer */
  delete &dp; // deleting a dangling pointer
}
```

In this example, it's behavior is random. It might crash, or it might point to another object depending on what happened to the memory it was at.